# Check for assertions in sqlx (Linting/Quality)

Tags: sql, assertion, dataform

I'm extremely sorry if this was not clear. I'm new to the forum so please excuse me. I meant to ask, we have linting rules in "sqlfluff" which we all use. Now, as part of linting, I want to check if my sql code has enough assertions (precisely I am using Dataform which has the BigQuery dialect of sql). Since I couldn't find an sqlfluff rule for check of assertions, I made a Python code which did the following: a) counts the number of sql statements (which are number of semi colons) b) Counts the assertion word c) Take the ratio of a) and b) and provides the information during the ci/cd lint job. Is this a valid approach? Are there any inbuilt functionality / linter I could use which does this?

IS this a justified approach? IS there any inbuilt rule that does it better? Any suggestions?

I tried steps 2,3,4 above and I'm trying to ask if there is anything better than what I have tried

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi,, I'm extremely sorry if this was not clear. I'm new to the forum so please excuse me. I meant to ask

Comment: I have reframed my question, again. Sorry.. hope its clearer now? I have edited the original question

Comment: Hi, @KajalChopra, please could you tell me how you manage to setup linting on your sqlx file using sqlfluff ? I didn't find a templater for sqlx in the documentation. Thanks